# Joomla template with giant menu

Tags: wordpress-theming, joomla-template

I am looking for a joomla or wordpress template (free | commercial) with giant menu.
I like such types of websites where you pull the menu and see evrything. It 
makes it easier for visitors to see the big picture instead of being forced
to navigate from page to page
examples : reuters.com, vmware.com etc

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't come across a theme persay, however there is [UberMenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/). A WP Plugin in for just such occasions.